# Undo soft delete in List

Tags: react-admin

I would like to be able to restore a soft delete from the list. How would one do this? I am thinking about creating a custom button with a custom action, but I can't get it to work. Maybe there's another way to achieve this?

Comment: Put the deleted elements into a "deleted" list then put them back when you want. If you want to put them back in the same location they were before then you would have to store that information with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to fix the problem on another way, not requiring a list of deleted items.

For anyone needing this answer: stay strong!